# Can you put a conditional statemnet inside a plot command in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have a set of data ( two columns 'food 1','food 2'+ label column ' taste').

I want to plot the two columns as X and Y and depending the label I want to change the shape of the marker. The label column is binary [ 0 , 1].

for exmaple:

```
data.plot(kind='scatter', x='food 1', y='food 2')
```

e.g. If the label is '0', I want to use a square marker and if '1', I want to use a triangle marker.

How to do that?

Comment: This is tagged as matplotlib but your syntax looks more like pandas.  Which plotting library are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't an API for applying conditionals to markers within a single call to scatter.

The usual solution is separate the points into two groups and call *scatter()* twice, once for the 0 labeled points and again for the 1 labeled points:

```
plt.scatter(x0, y0, marker='s')
plt.scatter(x1, y1, marker='^')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do inline if-else statements in Python like:

```
marker='^' if (label=='0') else 's'
```

Comment: How would you use this in the context of the question?

Comment: I tried : 
**data.plot(kind='scatter', x='food 1', y='food 2', marker='^' if ('taste'=='0') else 's'
, figsize=(12,8))** 
they all become sqaures